# How to create a tooltip in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

i've just started to learn XNA and i want to make a tooltip? I've googled but not found any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

if (ms.X == YourPoint.X && ms.X == YourPoint.X)
{
   SpriteBatch.DrawString(ToolTipFont, "A tooltip!", new Vector2(ms.X,ms.Y),Color.White);
}
```

You could and also should use [Rectangle.Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx) for an easy way to see if the mouse is over it. Ex:

```
MouseRect = new Rectangle(ms.X,ms.Y,1,1) 
if (MouseRect.Intersects(YourPoint.X,YourPoint.Y,WidthOfArea,HeightOfArea))
```